# Icon cache in Shopware 6 let's icons disappear after all.js is loaded

Tags: svg, shopware6

When `Settings-> System->Storefront->Activate icon cache` is activated, the download center plugin does not show icons after the page is loaded (before all.js is parsed, the icons are briefly displayed).

Is seems to be related to this new feature: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/UPGRADE-6.4.md#new-twig-filter-sw_icon_cache

We want to understand this better: Is there Javascript involved in parsing the icons or is this likely another bug?

What we saw is, that the icon cache seems to print the SVGs only once and then uses xlink in referencing subsequent uses of the icon:

```
<span class="icon icon-circle-download icon-md">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><defs><path d="m13 14.5858 [svg code shortend by me] 4.4993-7.7954z" id="icons-default-circle-download" /></defs><use xlink:href="#icons-default-circle-download" fill="#758CA3" fill-rule="evenodd" /></svg>
</span>

....

<span class="icon icon-circle-download icon-md">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><use xlink:href="#icons-default-circle-download" fill="green"></use></svg>
</span>
```

What can be possible causes that the Javascript execution removes the icons?

[image]